# Replacing one value in R data set

Tags: r

I have a data set for R where everything is pretty good, except what I need to be 0 to do calculations is 100 in my data set. How do I change all of the 100s in my data set to zero? Which functions do I use? I need to replace all of the 100 values in the “Grades” column with 0.

I tried to use mutate and case-when, and I just got error messages.

Comment: Try `df[df$Grades == 100, “Grades”] <- 0` (assuming your data are names “df”)

Answer (score 1):

In dplyr, we can use `case_match` or `replace`

```
df %>%
    mutate(grades = case_match(grades, 100 ~ 0, .default = grades))

df %>%
    mutate(grades = replace(grades, grades == 100, 0))
```